# Get field from Firestore and use it to update another collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

There are two collections "UserWithUidAndPoints" and "Points Value"

```
exports.useWildcard = 
    functions.firestore.document('UserWithUidAndPoints/{userId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        const data = change.after.data();
        const previousData = change.before.data();

    admin.firestore().collection("PointsValue").doc("ADMIN12345678").get().then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
      } else {
       //Use the fields from doc.data() below
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
      }
        })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting document', err);
    });
```

How to get "doc.data" and use it below to update values

```
    admin.firestore().collection("UserWithUidAndPoints").doc(refId).update({
      "TotalRefers": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),

      "Points": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(doc.data.InviteX) //Here
  })
    return change.after.ref.set({
      Points: count + 25
    }, {merge: true});

});
```

Comment: [link](https://neibar.page.link?apn=com.logical.neibar&ibi=com.example.ios&link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Finvitedby%3D0RF2EspIrZVZIeZ7i1n6PPvJGdT2)

Answer (score 0):

Move the whole `admin.firestore().collection("UserWithUidAndPoints").doc(refId).update({...})` part where your data is:

```js
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such document!');
} else {
  // Move it here
  console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
}
```

Since the update requires data from another request, `else` block (which represents a successful response) above is where the update should occur.